# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipython==7.23.1

Tags: python, docker, scipy, ipython

## Environnement

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Docker: v20.10.6
- Docker-compose: v1.27.4
- Python (in container): v3.6.13

## Situation

Hi, I'm trying to setup docker container for a flask application. I was developping my application and I needed to use openCV and scipy to make image processing. I tried to reproduce this tutorial : https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781785282690/1/ch01lvl1sec11/generating-a-warming-cooling-filter.

Before install scipy : https://www.scipy.org/install.html#pip-install, all work's well but after installation I got error.
Before installation I had not `ipython` in my `requirements.txt`

When I start my docker container I got :

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipython==7.23.1

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

WORKDIR /app

ENV FLASK_APP api
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_ENV development
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv

# Init virtualenv:
RUN pip install virtualenv
RUN virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# Install dependencies:
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y

# Run the application:
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

## Error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipython==7.23.1 (from versions: 0.10, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 4.0.0b1, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.1.0rc1, 4.1.0rc2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 5.0.0b1, 5.0.0b2, 5.0.0b3, 5.0.0b4, 5.0.0rc1, 5.0.0, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.2, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.5.0, 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.8.0, 5.9.0, 5.10.0, 6.0.0rc1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.5.0, 7.0.0b1, 7.0.0rc1, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.4.0, 7.5.0, 7.6.0, 7.6.1, 7.7.0, 7.8.0, 7.9.0, 7.10.0, 7.10.1, 7.10.2, 7.11.0, 7.11.1, 7.12.0, 7.13.0, 7.14.0, 7.15.0, 7.16.0, 7.16.1)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for ipython==7.23.1
> ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1

How can I resolve this error ? Did I miss something ?

Thanks in adance

Comment: I don't think you need ipython for this, nor do you really need a virtualenv in a docker container. So remove ipython from the requirements.txt

Comment: If this is someone else's Flask application, then the question is off topic for Stack Overflow; we are not technical support. If it is yours, then presumably you are responsible for the requirements specified in `requirements.txt`; is there a particular reason why the project requires ipython at all, let alone a specific version?

Comment: I never installed ipython, I'm going to try to remove it @C.Nivs

Comment: I got another error : ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib==3.4.2 ... matplotlib==3.4.2 @C.Nivs

Comment: @Karl Knechtel It's not a fork of an application made by someone, I had no error but when I tried to install https://www.scipy.org/install.html, I got this error

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't know why the version of ipython is 7.23.1 but it's linked to scipy installation, how can i resolve this ?